# Landscape Mode in WeeApp

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, jailbreak

I know there are a lot solved questions about `UIDeviceOrientation` in iOS, but no one worked for me. I want to make a label in the `Widget` centered in Landscape mode.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
if (([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
    ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight))
{
     d = 516; //my var to change the Position (The Value is just a test)
}
```

And this doesn't work for me for some reason...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured this out for my widget today. Define the method

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(int)arg1
```

for your AppController. Inside, check which orientation arg1 corresponds to with

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(arg1)) {
    // you're in landscape mode
    float screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
}
else {
    // you're in portrait mode
    float screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
}
```

You can see my implementation of this in my file [here](https://github.com/andrewmm/ncwunderground/blob/master/ammNCWundergroundController.m). I figured it out by looking at the code for [WeeFacebook](https://github.com/forensix/WeeFacebook2.0/blob/master/FacebookWeeApp/FacebookWeeApp.mm).